# Good practice. Storing an address coming from value in vector

Tags: c++

Here is an example:

```
class Log
{
    void AddLogger(ILogger& oLogger) noexcept
    {
        m_oLoggers.emplace(&oTracer);
    }

    std::vector<ILogger*> m_oLoggers;
}

class FileLogger : public ILogger{}

FileLogger myLogger{};
Log myLog{};
myLog.AddLogger(myLogger);
```

Here `myLogger` and `myLog` have the same lifetime because they are in the same scope. I use a vector of pointer because I don't want to copy my Iloggers. But is it safe to work with a value when an object has to be shared ? Maybe Should I use a pointer (smart or not) to put `myLogger` in the heap not in the stack ? What's your opinion, is it possible to keep a "value semantic" ?

Comment: side note: `emplace` is not `noexcept` and so you shouldn't make `AddLogger` `noexcept`

Comment: In this case you control the scope of `myLog` and `myLogger`, but is this always the case? Having a `vector` invloved suggests more ILoggers may follow. Who controls and establishes the lifetime of other logs? Is there a remover of logs? Cannot answer this question as posed.

Comment: A vector of pointers is not uncommon, although perhaps less so with readily available smart pointers.  As a side note, if you're using a pointer, pass a pointer. Intent in code is important when you come back in 6 months or more and have to remember what you meant.

Comment: @bolov it's a good point, I didn't notice this point.

It was an example to illustrate my question, not a specific problem. Finally Ninja answered to my question : AddLogger(...) should have a pointer parameter, and only the caller is in charge of the lifetime of this parameter (here it's myLogger).
Thank you.